# Best practices for generating a tnsnames.ora entry

Tags: oracle, network, client

I need to integrate some scripts that export and import data from Oracle databases. They are shell scripts that rely on the TNS name being set up (e.g., scott/tiger@tns).

The application owners are likely not going to change the scripts to support EZConnect syntax, so my best option right now is to automate the TNS name setup. The file, for reference, sits here:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

Is there already a best practice / existing utility for doing this? Or am I just going to have to write a shell script to pump out the task?

Comment: What part are you looking to automate? Adding entries to local files? Or distribution of one centrally maintained file? Which platform(s) are you on?

Comment: Adding entries to the local files. On SuSE 11 SP3. I am thinking of adding a bash function to transform the arguments to sqlplus to use the EZConnect format now.

Comment: There used to a global naming service called onames. But I can not recommend it. Oracle never made it stable and the onames server crashes from time to time. I also think that somebody reverse-engineered its protocol and there is somewhere on the internet downloadable alternative implementation for the onames server.

Comment: I think onames was deprecated in 10g. Either openLDAP or ORacle Internet Directory (OID) are better ways to keep track of database connections. If you use OID, you might be able to setup single sign on. But OID is a separate product with a separate license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by inserting the hostname/dbname on the fly from a global environment variable called $connString. Sample code:

```
tnsOverride() {
    index=0
    for var in "$@"
    do
        index=$((index + 1))
        if [[ $var =~ ^.+@.+$ ]]; then
            # connect string found
            var=`echo $var | sed -e "s#@.*#@${connString}#g"`
            set -- "${@:1:$((index - 1))}" ${var} "${@:$((index + 1))}"
        fi
    done
    echo "$@"
}

sqlplus() {
    set -- `tnsOverride "$@"`
    command sqlplus $@
}

expdp() {
    set -- `tnsOverride "$@"`
    command expdp $@
}

impdp() {
    set -- `tnsOverride "$@"`
    command impdp $@
}

export -f tnsOverride sqlplus expdp impdp
```

Any subsequent shell scripts dispatched from an environment with these functions set up will override the arguments on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using tnsnames, I have used openLDAP to do the names resolution.
You can replicate across two nodes if you want. As soon as you change the entry in openLDAP every server has the new information. You can even get the resolution from an ssl encrypted port if you want.

[using openLDAP the name resolution](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LDAP/LDAP_8.shtml)